# Distribution of a exponetial Random Variable

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus, exponential-distribution

i have a stopping time $T$ of an Poisson Process $N$ with rate $\lambda$.
Somehow this stopping time is exponential distributed. 
So we have $ T \sim exp(\lambda)$.

I want to know the distribution of the following term:
\begin{align}
\exp(-\kappa \cdot T)  \mathbb{1}_{\{ T < \tau \} }
\end{align}

where $\tau$ is fixed and $\kappa$ is actually a intensity rate of another Poisson Process. But unter the circumstances we can hold $\kappa$ and find the fitting distrbution. Thanks for your help.

Best Regards

frakChris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean that $\kappa$ and $\tau$ are positive constants. Let $X = \exp(-\kappa T)1_{\{T < \tau\}}$ be the random variable of interest. Since there is an indicator, we can first easily see that it is a mixture of continuous and discrete random variable, with a point mass at $0$:

$$ \Pr\{X = 0\} = \Pr\{T \geq \tau\} = e^{-\lambda\tau}$$

and it has a continuous support on the interval $[e^{-\kappa\tau},1]$. For $x \in [e^{-\kappa\tau},1],$ we can calculate the CDF as

$$ \begin{align} 
\Pr\{X \leq x\} & = \Pr\{X = 0\} + \Pr\{e^{-\kappa\tau} < X \leq x\} \\
& = e^{-\lambda\tau} + \Pr\left\{-\frac {\ln x} {\kappa} \leq T < \tau \right\}\\
& = \exp\left\{\frac {\lambda \ln x} {\kappa}\right\} \\
& = x^{\lambda/\kappa}
\end{align}$$

As for the expectation, we can directly use the CDF obtained here, as $X$ is a non-negative random variable:

$$ \begin{align} 
E[X] &= \int_0^{+\infty} 1 - F_X(x)dx \\
&= (1-e^{-\lambda\tau})e^{-\kappa\tau} 
+ \int_{e^{-\kappa\tau}}^1 1 - x^{\frac {\lambda} {\kappa}}dx \\
& = (1-e^{-\lambda\tau})e^{-\kappa\tau} 
+ \left.x - \frac {\kappa} {\lambda + \kappa} x^{\frac {\lambda + \kappa} {\kappa}} \right|_{x=e^{-\kappa\tau}}^{x=1} \\
&= -e^{-(\lambda+\kappa)\tau} + 1 - \frac {\kappa} {\lambda + \kappa}
+ \frac {\kappa} {\lambda + \kappa}e^{-(\lambda+\kappa)\tau} \\
&= \frac {\lambda} {\lambda + \kappa}(1 - e^{-(\lambda+\kappa)\tau})
\end{align}$$

Comment: heyhey,
the calulations makes totally sense to me. Thanks i didnt think of looking the the support.


On the other hand I want to calculate the EV of $exp(−κT)1{T<τ}$ now.
For that I did the follow calc's:
\begin{align*}
E( \exp(−\kappa)1{< \tau})
 & = \int_{\Omega} \exp(−\kappa T)1_{\{T < \tau \}} dP \\
& = P(\exp(− \kappa T) < x )\\
& = P(\exp(- \kappa T) < x ) \\
& = P( - T < \frac{ln(x)}{\kappa} ) \\
& = 1- P( T < \frac{ln(x)}{\kappa} )  \\
& = \exp(-\lambda \frac{ln(x)}{\kappa})
\end{align*}
and since $T$ is supposed to exp-distrubted with $\lambda$ i got the result.

Comment: But the solution is supposed to be:
\begin{align*}
\frac{ \lambda }{ \lambda + \kappa}
 (1 - \exp(- (\lambda + \kappa) \tau))
\end{align*} 

which i really cant explain. Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Edit made accordingly as the expected value is requested.

Comment: Thank you so much. That really helped!